# At my beginning there's a vessel, you can slash me with a chisel

Tags: riddle, word

> *At my beginning there's a vessel,*
>   *You can slash me with a chisel.*
>   *I belong to the first from a total of four,*
>   *There's nothing to add more ...*

Who/ what am I?

Hint 1

> The Windowmaker

Hint 2

> Blocks

Hint 3

> $\sin$, $\cos$, $\tan$ are ........ in nature.

Comment: Does this need a [tag:knowledge] tag? The hint makes me think it might be some popular-culture thing ...

Comment: My initial thought was that this is related to Minecraft lol, since if you have Bonus Chest on, the beginning of the game contains a chest (a vessel for items?) that you can break with a chisel (any tool, really), and it spawns with four torches around it. Doesn't sound anywhere close but that was my initial thought ;P

Comment: Sorry it's not.

Comment: According to @JS1's answer, it is related to minecraft.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The answer is Potassium(as in your comments)

At my beginning there's a vessel,

> The word **pot**(As by **JS1**)

You can slash me with a chisel.

> It is very soft metal, so it can be easily cut by a chisel, which is used for cutting the wood or soft elements.

I belong to the first from a total of four,

> From hint blocks, there are four blocks in periodic table s,p,d,f. It comes in s-block

There's nothing to add more ...

> It is very highly reactive in nature, so we can not add anything with it.

Answer (score 4):

> I think the answer is **potassium**

At my beginning there's a vessel,

> The word **pot**

You can slash me with a chisel.

> Refers to Minecraft, which has a potassium block.  (I've never played Minecraft so I'm basing this off Googling)

I belong to the first from a total of four,

> First column, fourth row of the periodic table

There's nothing to add more ...

> Don't know this one

Hint 1: The Windowmaker

> Microsoft, which makes Windows and Minecraft

Hint 2: Blocks

> Minecraft

Hint 3: sin, cos, tan are ........ in nature

> Periodic, as in the periodic table

Comment: Wow, correct answer. Try working with all the lines.

Comment: @Ak19 Is that the correct interpretation of “first from a total of four”?  If so then I’m not seeing the “total” at all.

Comment: @ErickWong No it's not. That's why I've mentioned to work with all the lines. Just the answer is correct.

Answer (score 3):

Is it a:

> Potstone?

At my beginning there's a vessel,

> A pot.

You can slash me with a chisel.

> Stone

I belong to the first from a total of four,

> The stone age was the first of the four ages (thanks @Erick Wong)

There's nothing to add more...

> Maybe just a good rhyming end to the riddle.

Hint 1:

> 

Hint 2:

> Blocks = Stone

Hint 3:

> Periodic (Again, credit to Erick Wong)

Comment: You're half correct, try mathematically with Hint 3

Comment: How about now? And hint one seems very confusing to me...

Comment: Perhaps first of 4 refers to the Stone Age being the first of 4 ages of technology.  And sin, cos, tan could be **period**ic.

Comment: Thanks, I will put that in my answer.

Comment: @Duck The first half i.e., Pot is correct, but it's not stone. Try connecting "periodic" and the first hint 2 hints, you'll reach the answer.

Answer (score 3):

As the answer is already out there (I think Asterisk explained it best) and I dont want to spoil the comments too much:

At my beginning there's a vessel

> Could be the soviet submarine "K-19" as K (Kalium or Potassium) is the 19. Element
>
>  Hint 1 should be "The widomaker" as in the Film "K-19: The Widowmaker"
>
>  [K-19: The Widowmaker is a 2002 historical submarine film about the first of many  disasters that befell the Soviet submarine K-19.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-19:_The_Widowmaker)

Something I noticed

> Authors name a**k19** ... the answer was there all the time

Comment: The Widowmaker makes a lot more sense than the Windowmaker, I agree.

Answer (score 2):

I definetly don't have it, but my first instinct tells me it's one of these answers

> **car tire** or **cartwheel**

At my beginning there's a vessel,

> **car** is in the beginning of both words. **cart** is also a vessel

You can slash me with a chisel.

> you can slash a tire or a wheel with a chisel

I belong to the first from a total of four,

> there are 4 tires in a car, and 4 wheels in a cart

There's nothing to add more ...

> I see nothing in this. I also am sure that my answer is wrong, because it doesn't fit any of the clues

Comment: Sorry it's not the right answer.

Comment: "*I also am sure that my answer is wrong, because it doesn't fit any of the clues*" - then why post it?